# How to safe Python multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread code in python like this. But I am not sure whether I am doing in correct way or not.

```
Class MyThread(threading.thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, thread_name):  
        self.thread_name = thread_name
        self.thread_id = thread_id

    def run(self):
        do_something()

def do_something():
    while True:
        do_something_else()
        time.sleep(5)


Class SomeClass:
    def __init__():
        pass
    def run():
        thread1 = MyThread(1, "thread1")
        thread2 = MyThread(2, "thread2")  
        thread3 = MyThread(3, "thread3")

def main():  
    agent = Someclass()  
    agent.run()
```

Whether this is the safe way to deal with multiple thread? How does it impact other applications? Is there a chance, that execution of one thread can hinder the execution of others? What happens , if the threads got blocked in any cycle?

Also how to make sure that,  thread doesn't gets blocked for forever b'coz of any reason. If it gets blocked , then after fixed timeinterval it should come out gracefully and continue in  next loop.

Comment: Did you run it? What's the result? What's the expected result?

Comment: what is do_something() and what is do_something_else()?

Comment: Yeah, I ran it. It works. I avoided the code of functions. do_something () is a method gets called by each thread and it contains do_something_else() method which need to get executed periodically by each thread. But I just tested by giving one print statement in do_something_else().

Answer (score 0):

That is why Python and some other languages introduce the `lock`

This [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) will help you, you need to read something about Lock, RLock and Condition

Comment: No, the logic in do_something_else() is different for different thread. And I want exactly like that, each thread should function independently. Also , the threads job are different from each other in my code.

Comment: That was my question actually, that whether this is the correct way to write multithread program or not?

Comment: ok, why you use while True: ? is this a consumer ? another thing I should remind you that.. the do_something() and do_something_else() are actually in the same work thread

Comment: The thread need to do something periodically thats why , while True: condition.

Comment: ok do_something() and do_something_else() are in the same thread... I doubt that is it "else"....?

Answer (score 0):

Your code's thread safety is really dependent on what's in `do_something()` and `do_something_else()`.  It's thread safe if you're only modifying local variables.  But the moment you start reading/modifying shared variables/storage, like a file or a global variable, then you need to use something like locks or semaphores to ensure thread safety.

You can read about Python's `threading` module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects).

This Wikipedia articles on [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) and [locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29) may be helpful to you too.

If you need examples for writing multi-threading code, here's a good [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) using different synchronization mechanisms.